# css class descendance understanding

Tags: html, css

I need to understand how I can implement something like this.
Suppose I have a main button class, say

```
.btn{
   font-family:Serif;
 }
```

now I want all buttons to have this font family, however then in different locations I want to have different font size such as

```
.btn-lrg{
   font-size:2.em;
 }
```

and then at another location I want font size to be smaller as

```
.btn-sml{
   font-size:0.5em
 }
 .btn-reg{
   font-size:1.0em
 }
```

How do I declare css code so that I can essentially use it as following(or pls point to the right syntax)

```
<button class="btn btn-lrg"><br/>
<button class="btn btn-reg"><br/>
<button class="btn btn-sml"><br/>
```

Thanks for guidance..

Comment: It should already work the way you wrote it. https://jsfiddle.net/c710dvrk/

Comment: TiiJ7
I think what meant was that .btn-lrg and other classes can only be used as I wrote, such as <button class="btn btn-lrg"><br/>
What I am getting as  that btn-lrg is a child class of btn..I hope I clarified..Thanks

Comment: So basically you want `btn-lrg` to inherit the styles from `btn` so you can simply do `<button class="btn-lrg">` ?

Comment: Yes, anyways, I think I accept your first response as my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you wrote in the OP will work fine that way you wrote it. But as clarified in the comments you basically want to do this:

```
<button class="btn-lrg">...</button>
```

And still keep the styles from `.btn`. Unfortunately, CSS doesn't have a way to "inherit" styles from another rule; but you can do something like this:

```
.btn, .btn-lrg, .btn-sml, .btn-reg {
    font-family: Serif;
}
.btn-lrg{
    font-size:2.0em;
}
.btn-sml{
    font-size:0.5em
}
.btn-reg{
    font-size:1.0em
}
```

The alternative is to use a CSS preprocessor, like LESS or SASS. The disadvantage is that every time you update the code you'll need to re-run it through the preprocessor (though this can possibly be automated)

**LESS:**

```
.btn {
    font-family: Serif;
}
.btn-lrg {
    .btn;
    font-size:2.0em;
}
/* ... */
```

**SASS:**

```
.btn {
    font-family: Serif;
}
.btn-lrg {
    @extend .btn;
    font-size:2.0em;
}
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `.btn` is only a "main" class in the sense that it carries properties you'd like to use more commonly. Other than that, the classes are on equal footing and will be handled as such. If you had competing property statements in several, such as `font-family`, then specificity becomes an issue.

As was commented above, you may use your classes as you've done without concern.

Answer (score -1):

If you want all buttons to have the same font family, you do not need to use a class.

```
button {
    font-family: Serif;
}
```

Applying a new class will not change the font-family unless you specify a new font-family in the class.